# Can I record programming presentation in PyCharm?

Tags: pycharm

I want to record programming session in Pycharm than reproduce it step by step as presentation?

How can I do it?

It can be recorded step by step (some block of program) or live with all what I write including errors and fixing is during presentation.

The easiest method is always copy-and-paste but maybe it is possible to do it in more interactive way with use built in plugins or external?

Comment: I don't know how to do this in PyCharm, but what I've done in the past for students is set up a zoom (or teams) meeting, share my screen, record the meeting and use that recording.

Comment: That is general recording. You can use Zoom, OBS, ... and record video that is true. I want to record coding process than replay - like presentation slides :). Maybe it is possible - maybe not.

Comment: From what I understand the more complicated solution would be an application automation script (depending on OS you could use [AutoIt](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1686975) for example) and have the session wait for some actions of you to post code, run, etc... If it's simply video recording any screen capture application on the OS level could do.

Comment: If you want to try plugins to record actions inside the IDE there are several options like [speacode](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/15672-speacode-video) try searching the [JetBrains marketplace](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/search?products=pycharm&search=record). I haven't tried any of these but plugins but some have good reviews. The best choice probably depends on how much work you want to put into it and how much automation you want to have.